# How can I apply the syntax of this function in R to my data file?

Tags: r, function, import

I'm trying to import some fluorescence data into a package in R. For unknown reasons, my fluorometer software doesn't give me an option to export in the format the package traditionally takes.

The package has a way of creating custom import functions explained [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/eemR/vignettes/custom-import-function.html). My data can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbFmomnyCzeJUzlGGL2vyslGcRlN814k9cDzJ8I5irw/edit?usp=sharing).

In my data, Cells $A2:$A50 are excitation wavelengths (exc), cells B$1:BP$1 are emission wavelengths (em), and all other cells (B2:BP50) are intensity/fluorescence (x).

I'm relatively new to R, and since my machine won't just give me the proper format, I'm not sure how to go about taking the documentation and making it work for me. Any help and tips would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi dogman, Welcome to Stack Overflow. We've all been there! Maybe you can help others understand your use case a bit better: can you include some code that you've tried (even if it doesn't quite do what you want) and maybe a description of what would happen if it _did_ do what you want?

Good news is this looks like it's going to work out without too much pain, seems like you have a matrix with row names and column names and you somehow need to orient your R package to that data structure...

Comment: The file you provided is a Google Sheets file and the instructions you included are for reading a text file in .csv format. Have you exported the Google Sheets file to a .csv file?

Comment: @Michael  Thank you; by new to R I mean I did some simple calculations with no package years ago - I have no clue what the syntax in the page I linked does - i.e., the na.omit[ ,1] type stuff. I'm not sure how to tell it which cells correspond with what variable, so I'm at a loss to get started. Is there a wiki somewhere that explains what the placement of numbers, commas, brackets, etc mean? Also  I have gotten the file in a csv; the sheets link was simply the easiest way I knew how to get the data to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the data as a .csv, it's pretty easy to convert it to eemR's preferred format. See below

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(eemR)

importIlliter <- function(file) {
  fluoroFrame <- fread(file) %>% as.data.frame()
  return(
    list(
      file = file,
      x = fluoroFrame[ -1, -1] %>% t() %>% as.matrix() %>% unname(),
      ex = fluoroFrame[ -1, 1] %>% as.numeric(),
      em = fluoroFrame[ 1, -1] %>% as.numeric()
    )
  )
}

eem <- eem_read("Desktop/2021/eemsDataReddit.csv", import_function = importIlliter)
```

The function does two main things: It reads in the data (using data.table's fread function) as a data.frame (fluoroFrame) and returns a list with the formatted data that eemR requires. The list has four entries

1. **file**: Self explanatory.
2. **x**: a matrix containing the intensity data from the csv. The [-1, -1] tells r to return all the data in fluoroFrame **except** for the first row and column. t() flips, or transposes, the matrix.
3. **ex**: A numeric vector containing the excitation wavelengths. [-1, 1] removes the first row, then takes the first column of fluoroFrame.
4. **em**: A numeric vector containing the emmision wavelengths. [1, -1] Takes the first row, and removes the first column in that row.

Comment: lmao i saw your reddit post and made a stack overflow account just to answer this question